# Logstash - IP against CIDR

Tags: logstash

Im using CIDR filter to check if an IP is inside some subnets.
I need to:

```
cidr {
                id => "netflow-postproc-cidr-src_addr"
                address => [ "%{[@metadata][netflow][src_addr]}" ]
                network => [ "0.0.0.0/32", "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16", "fc00::/7", "127.0.0.0/8", "::1/128", "169.254.0.0/16", "fe80::/10", "224.0.0.0/4", "ff00::/8", "255.255.255.255/32", "::" ]
                add_field => { "[@metadata][netflow][src_locality]" => "private" }
            }
```

What I need is to get which subnet has matched IP and not only if "at least one".

For example If i have 172.16.0.10 I need to fill a new field with 172.16.0.0/12

EXAMPLE WHAT I NEED

```
cidr {
     id => "netflow-cidr-src_addr"
     address => [ "%{[@metadata][netflow][src_addr]}" ]
     network_path => "/etc/logstash/dictionaries/internal_subnet.yml"
     add_field => { "[@metadata][netflow][src_subnet]" => "<subnet_that_match>" }
      }
```

Comment: write what your input looks like and how the output should be with a sample data that resembles your data

Answer (score 0):

If you need each of the 13 networks to be tagged differently then you will need to use 13 different cidr filters.

Comment: Has you can see in the Example above, subnet list is inside a dictionary that changes so I cant modify the pipeline. I need an adaptive approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there isnt a solution so I have found a workaroud.
Knowing every CIDR, I made a python procedure to create an entry for memcached with every IPs in every subnets.

```
all_su = Subnet.objects.all()
for iss in all_su:
    net = ip_network(iss.cidr)
    ## ITERATING ALL IP INSIDE CIDR
    for i in net:
       #creating memcached entry
```

So in memcahced I have something like this:

```
subnet-namespace:172.16.0.10-subnet-cidr = 172.16.0.0/12
subnet-namespace:172.16.0.11-subnet-cidr = 172.16.0.0/12
subnet-namespace:172.16.0.12-subnet-cidr = 172.16.0.0/12
[...]
```

Then in logstash I can check in memcached with default filter:

```
memcached {
                hosts => ["localhost:11211"]
                namespace => "subnet-namespace"
                get => {
                    "%{[source][ip]}-subnet-cidr"           => "[source][subnet]                
                }
                add_tag => ["source_subnet_cached"]
    }
```